# Why does the -bs switch on sendmail cause a SELinux denial from within a PHP app?

Tags: sendmail, selinux

On a CentOS 7.5 server (LAMP, PHP-FPM) with SELinux enabled, I've encountered a strange issue with a Laraval 5.3 application when it tries to send email.

The application's mail config is set to use `/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs` and when attempting to send an email the application throws a `Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""' in vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383`

Suspecting SELinux, I dug deeper and `audit2why` shows:

`type=AVC msg=audit(1553606152.177:1240981): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=3896 comm="sendmail" name="smtpd" dev="vda1" ino=12904557 scontext=system_u:system_r:system_mail_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:postfix_smtpd_exec_t:s0 tclass=file`

If I disable SELinux, the issue is resolved. If I use the `mail` driver instead, which I believe instructs SwiftMailer to use PHP's `mail()` function (and subsequently the sendmail bin with only `-t -i` switches as per the default php.ini config) it works. If I use the SMTP driver it works and if I change the Laraval mail config sendmail path to `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i` it works.

Why does SELinux complain when using the `-bs` switch on sendmail?

According to `man sendmail`:

```
-bs Stand-alone SMTP server mode. Read SMTP commands from standard input, and write responses to standard output.  In stand-alone SMTP server mode, mail relaying and other access controls are disabled by default. To enable them, run the process as the mail_owner user.
```

If one were to go ahead and use that configuration (I'm guessing it's there for a reason), is it really expected to compile and install an SELinux module to allow the behaviour? It seems like something that should Just WorkTM.

Bonus question: I was under the impression that the sebool `httpd_can_sendmail` needed to be `1` for PHP to be able to use `mail`. Certainly I've found that to be the case on other projects. This flag seems to have no affect whatsoever when using any of the above mail drivers, in that they all still work without it being on (apart from the `-bs` scenario above). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, (web) apps should not be exec-ing smtpd. That's better managed and secured on a central SMTP server. SELinux succeeded at restricting sendmail to be only a mail submission agent.

The alternative sendmail invocation queues mail without starting smtpd, which is allowed under this policy.

Booleans had no effect because this wasn't a transition from httpd context. Note the denial was `system_mail_t` to `postfix_smtpd_exec_t`. The default policy doesn't allow sendmail to exec smtpd at all.

Comment: TL;DR: Install an actual mailer such as ssmtp to handle relaying of mail from your web application.

Comment: How is that better or different from using sendmail/postfix to relay mail?

Comment: You can use sendmail / postfix, but not this option to fork smpd. It is generally better to not open a port or bother forking if you don't have to, less security exposure.